# ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.js

Tags: angular, firebase

An error in the AngularJs Program

`ERROR in node_modules/@angular/fire/database/interfaces.d.ts(2,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase'.
node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,79): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'firebase'.`

Comment: ERROR in node_modules/@firebase/firestore-types/index.d.ts(17,48): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types'.
node_modules/angularfire2/angularfire2.d.ts(3,52): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types'.
node_modules/angularfire2/database/database.d.ts(2,34): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@firebase/database-types'.

Comment: ERROR in node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts(2,42): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/Abeja/Documents/FormularioParque/node_modules/firebase/index"' has no exported member 'functions'.

Comment: npm install firebase

Comment: Ty Harsh pastel